# java native memory analysis in alpine

Tags: java, c, native, jna, alpine-linux

My Java application uses some c code with the use of JNA library. Application runs inside the ARM based Alpine container. When the application runs for long time the container memory consumption is keep on increasing. JVM memory allocation is constant and it's under that, but looks like native memory is keep on increasing.

For GNU bases Linux OS we jemallac works good for Java native memory analysis, but I can't find jemalloc support for MUSL based Linux like Alpine.

How I can do the Java native memory analysis in Alpine?

I initially though of using `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking`, but it's not of mush use in this case.